# Include transient domain class properties as restful json or xml response in grails

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

I have read numerous ways to *try* and achieve this, but I would have thought it would be fairly easy?

Given a domain class:

```
class DomainClassTest{
    String foo
    String bar

    //add accessor
    String getMessage() {
        "Hello"
    }
}
```

I would like to include the transient property `message` in both XML and JSON responses.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

I have read the documentation on renderers; http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#renderers

I have tried the following:

**DomainClassTestController.groovy:**

```
class DomainClassTestController extends RestfulController<DomainClassTestController>{
    static responseFormats = ['xml','json']

    DomainClassTestController() {
        super(DomainClassTest)
    }
}
```

**/conf/spring/resources.groovy**

```
beans = {
    xmlDomainClassTestRenderer(XmlRenderer, DomainClassTest) {
        includes = ['message']
    }
    jsonDomainClassTestRenderer(JsonRenderer, DomainClassTest) {
        includes = ['message']
    }
}
```

Simple enough, but a JSON/XML GET request returns empty.

I find it hard to believer there isn't a simple way to modify the response without using `ObjectMarshallers` or converters?

Comment: Using custom marshellers is the correct approach. That's how you customize the XML and JSON responses for your domain classes in Grails.

Comment: Alright ... it is what it is then! thanks for the info. I will look at custom marshellers then!

Comment: This should be a great resource to give you an example of how it can be done, and quite nicely too: http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue as well, and found there is very useful plugin for customizing the marshalling/rendering behavior of Domain objects:
"[marshallers](http://grails.org/plugin/marshallers)"

Be aware that for each Domain with which you use plugin (specifying "marshalling" on the class), it will circumvent anything settings you make in resources.groovy regarding the rendering of your domain. (This is actually a good thing IMHO, as it allows you to keep the rendering details about your Domain class in the same place as the class.)

So your example Domain class would look like this:

```
class DomainClassTest {
  static marshalling = {
    virtual {
        message { value, json -> json.value(value.getMessage()) }
    }
  }

  String foo
  String bar

  //add accessor
  String getMessage() {
      "Hello"
  }
}
```